# Magento get ids of shipping method, payment method and order status

Tags: magento, methods, module

How do I call the IDs of the shipping method, payment method and order status. I've only found that `getShippingDescription();` returns the fulltext of the method and getShippinid(); doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get these details of an order. IF so you can use the code below :

```
     /*Just loading the Orders Collections*/
     $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
     /*Getting the First Order details in the collection*/  
     echo '<br/>Order Status : '.$order->getFirstItem()->getData('status');
     echo '<br/>Order Shipping method : '.$order->getFirstItem()->getData('shipping_method');
     $order_id = $order->getFirstItem()->getData('entity_id');
     /*Loading the Payments of an order*/
     $orderPayment = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_payment_collection')
                     ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                     ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id',$order_id);
     echo '<br/>Order Payment method : '.$orderPayment->getFirstItem()->getMethod();
     echo '<br/>Order Payment Id: '.$orderPayment->getFirstItem()->getData('entity_id');
```

Also have a look at my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15250093/777103 for the best approach